# html mailer in php - NicEdit images disappers from mail

Tags: php, html, email, nicedit

I'm writing a program to send `html` embedded mail. For this purpose I've used [NicEdit - WYSIWYG editor](http://nicedit.com/). When I do send a mail, the images disappears in the mail.

In php `mail()` I've used `headers` as:

```
$header="From: no-reply@prithviassociates.org\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n".
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n".
        "Reply-To: info@prithviassociates.org\r\nBcc: ".$recipients."\r\n";
```

where `$recipients` contains the email addresses of recipients.

Any solution of this problem?

**Code**

*NicEdit Configuration*

```
<script src="js/nicedit.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new nicEditor().panelInstance('message');
    });
</script>
```

*HTML mailer form*

```
<form method="post" action="mailProcess.php">
    To <input type="text" name="recipients">
    Subject <input type="text" name="subject">
    Message
    <textarea cols="70" rows="15" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

*mailProcess.php*

```
$recipients = $_POST['recipients'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$header = "From: no-reply@prithviassociates.org\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: info@prithviassociates.org\r\nBcc: " . $recipients . "\r\n";
```

If I do upload an image then `NicEdit` gives a link like `<img width="524" src="http://i.imgur.com/ycyrMau.jpg"></img>` and when I submit the form for mailing the image disappears from the mail `message`

Comment: how do you insert images in the email? Are you embedding images in the email itself or using links? can you provide whole code creating the email?

Comment: `NicEdit` automatically inserts link and `html` in the message. `NicEdit` is a `WYSIWYG` editor.

Comment: Check HTML generated by NicEdit to see where are image links pointing to. First of all you should know whether you want to send images attached in the email or you want to place them on your website somewhere and then just link them from html in the email body.

Comment: Is there any other alternative for making an `html` mailer?

Comment: But what code it actually inserts? Links to images should be full links (eg. http: //somedomain.com/img/image1.jpg ). Of course most email clients will disable pictures for security reasons, displaying option to show them. You can also embed images into your email, but that more complicated than just putting html into mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `gmail` I'm able to tackle with this problem.

In `gmail` (*standard view*) I found `Message text garbled?` which showed me the actual content of the mail, which was in my case: `<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/CvToS30.jpg\" width=\"176\">`. It contains `\`s before every `"` which I've removed from `stripslashes()` as:

```
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
```

and now it works.

Comment: I don't understand why you needed gmail to check your html code :-)

Comment: It could help other people solving same problem if you find out why backslashes were there and then put it into the answer marked as the correct and final one. Cheers

Comment: @lot: I tried to check the source code of the message being send, but it instead showed me `Array()` and if I tried `print_r($_POST)` then it showed me proper html content which I want to send. So, with `gmail`'s *Message text garbled?* I found the exact code being received.

Comment: I don't know why but `NicEdit` had added `\` before every `"` automatically on server. Might be due to server configuration or else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `mail logs`? Is there any link to an image or error of some sort?

Comment: I'm writing an application `html mailer` through which I've to send mails

Comment: @MohammadFaisal : Yes, what i am saying is, If you are sending a mail, there has to be some sort of mail log on your server, where the HTML of the sent mail along with the headers is displayed. I personally use `mutt`

Comment: you can also try to add the following line in header:
`header('Content-Disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: image/png');'